# How do I find the maximum of each dimension in a cell array of matrices?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, max

I am given a cell array `A` which consists of matrices of different sizes.  For example, I could have a three element cell array where the dimensions for each element are:

```
A{1} -> 4 x 3
A{2} -> 16 x 4
A{3} -> 5 x 14
```

How would I traverse through the cell array and return the maximum for **each dimension** overall?  For example, the expected output of this operation with the example `A` above should give:

```
[16 14]
```

This is because by examining the first dimension, the maximum number of rows over the three matrices is 16.  Similarly, the maximum number of columns over the three matrices is 14.

Comment: Your example doesn't match the description. You probably mean something like: `A={ones(4,3), ones(16,4), ones(5,14)}`

Comment: @user3185893: I deleted my answer because I obviously understood your question in a wrong way. I assumed `[16,14]` to be the expected output for the provided example. What is the expected output for that example?

Comment: @knedlsepp, yes , your right :)  I mean A{ [4x3], [16x4], [5x14]}

Comment: Please edit your question then to clarify

Comment: @Daniel , the expected output is a matrix like [16x14] . this is the biggest possible size of a matrix that we can make with the cell of that array

Comment: @user3185893 please update your question. With Luis Mendo you got another matching your example data but not what your want!

Comment: OK, so you have a cell array that consists of **matrices** in each cell that conform to the sizes in `A`?  i.e. `A{1}` is a 4 x 3 matrix, `A{2}` is a 16 x 4 matrix, etc.?  I'm tempted to close this question because you don't seem to know what you want.... or you do know but you're obviously not making yourself clear.

Comment: @rayryeng I voted to close actually. Very unclear

Comment: @LuisMendo - heheheh. Well now that I've read Daniel's answer, I've rewritten the question.  I think it better captures what the OP was really after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My original answer returned the maximum element of the cell. Now including your comments the right code:

knedlsepp basically got it. Minor improvement in performance:

```
[a(:,1),a(:,2)]=cellfun(@size,A);
max(a)
```

Comment: It is not a good Idea!! my cell array includes 1,500,000 cells and each of cells have different size ! converting to a matrix make my memory sucks! I am trying to initialize my huge cell arrays with matrices inside of it to increase the performance! That's why I need to find the max possible size of matrix inside of my cell array for initilizing the following cell array with that size

Comment: By the way, your code returns the value of the the matrix not the size of matrix !!! I need the maximum possible size of a matrix in a cell array not the value!

Comment: @user3185893 - At least you got an answer.  A kind nudge saying "thank you for this answer, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for because <insert reason here>" would have gone down better. By reading your comment(s), I interpret this as you belittling Daniel's effort. BTW +1 Daniel.

Comment: Wow. Didn't know you could do this. I might need to rethink all my past uses of `'UniformOutput'`.

Comment: @knedlsepp - Neither did I, hence my +1.  I'd give more if I could!

Comment: That's what I get from believing in MATLAB's error messages: `Non-scalar in Uniform output, at index 1, output 1. Set 'UniformOutput' to false.`. This should read: *Read the docs and use multiple outputs!*

Comment: Can you really do that? `cellfun(@size, {[1 1], [2 2 })` gives me an error

Comment: THX Danie, This is exactly that I needed :) Sorry for my wrong description.

Comment: @LuisMendo: `nargout` of `cellfun` has to be equal to `nargout` of the function handle.

Comment: @all - I've rewritten the question so that it actually reflects what the OP wants.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the effort. Retracting close vote

Comment: @rayryeng, THX for editing my question and sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: @user3185893 - No problem. We here at StackOverflow frequently seek out what people are actually asking for when it is originally unclear. I'm just glad we figured out what you really wanted in the end.  I actually wish there was a badge for determining what the question is trying to describe when it was originally unclear... something like a Mentalist badge lol.

Comment: @rayryeng Looks to me like a very good idea! You could propose that in Meta. And maybe use this question as example :-D

Comment: @rayryeng, Frankly, my Matlab software was working when I was writting my question, and such a huge data processing didn't let me to open my workspace to check that how to define my cell array content in a proper way for my question :) Thx for your editing and thx @ Daniel for your nice answer

Comment: @LuisMendo - ahahahaha! that would be a nice badge to introduce, but I'm not sure how one could count how many times this situation happens automatically.  I suspect that this would have to resort to user intervention and let other people judge it.  Automatically awarding and judging of an unclear post and it becoming clear will be a bit hard.  Any ideas!?

Comment: @rayryeng I hadn't thought of that. Yes, it would be hard to determine automatically. Maybe the number of votes of the question could be used. But then it wouldn't be "mentalist"; rather, it would be something more general (in the mood of the "Reversal" badge: provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score)

Comment: @LuisMendo - That is certainly true! I'd still like to see how this badge plays out :) I may suggest something on Meta.

Comment: @rayryeng Let me know if you do!

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for:

```
max(cell2mat(cellfun(@size,A(:),'uni',0)),[],1)
```