# Removing zeros and then vertically collapse the matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

In MATLAB, say I have a set of square matrices, say A, with trace(A)=0 as follows:

For example,

```
A = [0 1 2; 3 0 4; 5 6 0]
```

How can I remove the zeros and then vertically collapse the matrix to become as follow:

```
A_reduced = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6]
```

More generally, what if the zeroes can appear anywhere in the column (i.e., not necessarily at the long diagonal)? Assuming, of course, that the total number of zeros for all columns are the same.

The matrix can be quite big (hundreds x hundreds in dimension). So, an efficient way will be appreciated.

Comment: Tried this before. This doesn't maintain the matrix structure - I'm referring to the "vertically collapsing the matrix" part.

Comment: Sorry. I think I have confused a lot of you when I used A' in my original post. I meant to indicate a changed / reduced A, not A transposed. I've now changed A' to A_reduced.

Comment: Shouldn't number of zeros in each row to be the same, rather than number of zeros in each column as stated in the question, to enable vertical collapsing? Something like this - `A = [0 3 0 2; 3 0 0 1; 7 0 6 0; 1 0 6 0;0 16 0 9]`?

Comment: Could you use a more random sample with `"total number of zeros for all columns are the same"` condition and state the desired output? For example something like this has two zeros in every column - `A = [0 3 7 1 0;3 0 0 0 6; 0 0 6 5 0;3 2 0 0 6]`, so what must be the expected output for this case?

Comment: Your example `A_reduced` assumes the number of zeros in all __rows__ is the same, and then can you compress __horizontally__. So your question is confusing. Anyway, I think my answer convers the two possibilities

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the various good answers you got, by clicking the green check mark on the left. So you indicate the system, that your problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To compress the matrix vertically (assuming every column has the same number of zeros):

  ```
  A_reduced_v = reshape(nonzeros(A), nnz(A(:,1)), []);
  ```
- To compress the matrix horizontally (assuming every row has the same number of zeros):

  ```
  A_reduced_h = reshape(nonzeros(A.'), nnz(A(1,:)), []).';
  ```

Answer (score 3):

**Case #1**

Assuming that `A` has equal number of zeros across **all rows**, you can compress it horizontally (i.e. per row) with this -

```
At = A' %//'# transpose input array
out = reshape(At(At~=0),size(A,2)-sum(A(1,:)==0),[]).' %//'# final output
```

Sample code run -

```
>> A
A =
     0     3     0     2
     3     0     0     1
     7     0     6     0
     1     0     6     0
     0    16     0     9
>> out
out =
     3     2
     3     1
     7     6
     1     6
    16     9
```

**Case #2**

If `A` has equal number of zeros across **all columns**, you can compress it vertically (i.e. per column) with something like this -

```
out = reshape(A(A~=0),size(A,1)-sum(A(:,1)==0),[])  %//'# final output
```

Sample code run -

```
>> A
A =
     0     3     7     1     0
     3     0     0     0    16
     0     0     6     6     0
     2     1     0     0     9
>> out
out =
     3     3     7     1    16
     2     1     6     6     9
```

Comment: _Now_ I understand your answer :-) The question kind of mixes both interpretations, doesn't it?

Comment: @LuisMendo Well that's what happens when *too symmetric or too simplistic* sample input is used to state a problem! :)

Comment: Exactly! One of my latest peeves (induced by this site) is how wrongly people choose their examples :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Another one is when I suggest a vectorized approach and OP comes back with - "Oh it's running out of memory! Because I am using  100 Billion data points!". I mean comeon, must have stated that at the start! :)

Comment: Very true. This reminds me, more generally, of the fact that some askers seem to think we are [mentalists](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28665186/2586922)

Comment: @LuisMendo haha that discussion!! Well, yeah I guess we are honing our "mentalist" skills too here on `SO`!! About the mentalist badge.. hmm `SO` must read our minds on when to award those :)

Comment: OK, that's it. I'm going to write a Meta post lol. I'll write it later tonight.

Comment: Thanks Divakar and Luis. Sorry for the confusing post but you guys presented a more general answer which should help others as well if somehow they need something similar.

Comment: @ValK Would be interesting to see which one turns out to be the most efficient one! Did you test out these solutions based on runtimes (efficiency)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work, quite fiddly to get the behaviour right with transposing:

```
>> B = A';
>> C = B(:);
>> reshape(C(~C==0), size(A) - [1, 0])'

ans =

     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
```

Comment: This solution works for me (with and without the transposing). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As your zeros are always in the main diagonal you can do the following:

```
l = tril(A, -1);
u = triu(A,  1);
out = l(:, 1:end-1) + u(:, 2:end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with almost the same solution as Mr E's though with another reshape command. This solution is more universal, as it uses the number of rows in `A` to create the final matrix, instead of counting the number of zeros or assuming a fixed number of zeros..

```
B = A.';
B = B(:);
C = reshape(B(B~=0),[],size(A,1)).'
```

Answer (score 0):

A correct and very simple way to do what you want is:

```
A = [0 1 2; 3 0 4; 5 6 0]

A =

 0     1     2
 3     0     4
 5     6     0

A = sort((A(find(A))))

A =

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6

A = reshape(A, 2, 3)

A =

 1     3     5
 2     4     6
```