# Generating random ellipses in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am going to generate random ellipses in Matlab. The information that I have is: distribution of large radius of ellipse, distribution of small radius of ellipse, and proportion (e.g., I want to stop this process after a certain amount, or proportion, of the grid is filled).

I tried the following code for circle:

```
out_size = [200 200];
out = zeros(out_size(1),out_size(2)); 
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:out_size(1),1:out_size(2));
for i=1:40
    obj = [random('unif',1,200) random('unif',1,200),random('unif',4,8)];
    d = sqrt((xx-obj(1)).^2 + (yy-obj(2)).^2);
    out(d <= obj(3))=1;
end
figure, imagesc(out), axis equal tight xy
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've got many ideas. What is the right question? BTW, an ellipsoid is a 3D object. Maybe ellipse?

Comment: What I meant was 2D ellipse. Actually I have the distributions of minor and major axis and I want to use them and generate a bunch of random ellipses on a grid (e.g. 200x200). I want to see a different image whenever I run it (it should depend on the seed number)

Comment: So what is the output required? Graphical representation? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. If you haven't tried anything, start researching the necessary functions in the docs.

Comment: So do you want to generate a bunch of random ellipses that all have varying major axes, minor axes, and centres?

Comment: Exactly, I also want these axis follow a Gaussian distribution (not unif)

Comment: So do you want to sample from a Gaussian distribution to obtain the major, minor axes + the centre, then draw these ellipses? Forgive my numerous questions.  I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to ask before writing an answer.  Also, I wouldn't recommend sampling from a Gaussian distribution as you will generate negative coefficients, and the major and minor lengths by definition are positive.

Comment: cool!  Interesting problem.  I'll try and write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those in the StackOverflow community that seem confused, I will rephrase what the question is asking (go Mentalist!).

---

The OP wishes to draw random ellipses in an image.  For each ellipse, we can characterize it by its major length, minor length and its centre location.  For each ellipse, the OP wishes to randomly sample from a distribution (Uniform, Gaussian, etc.) to obtain a major length, a minor length and the centre locations.  Once these are generated, the OP wishes to draw these onto an image.

The amount of ellipses to generate is contingent on the proportion of painted pixels drawn on this image.  Should the amount of painted pixels exceed a certain amount, we stop drawing.

---

You seem to be on the right track.  However, what I would do is generate the major, minor and centre coordinates first.  After, you can use a loop to loop over each quartet of parameters, generate the correct spatial locations for the ellipse, then use these locations to index into your image and set an intensity.  I'm going to be playful and I will randomize the intensity to set for each ellipse.  However, to be sure you can see the ellipse, I will restrict the intensities generated between `[32,255]`.

In addition, I would recommend you **don't** sample from a Gaussian distribution for the major and minor lengths, as the definition of these require they be positive.  Now, to review, the equation of an ellipse, given a centre point `(x_0, y_0)` and major and minor lengths `(a,b)` is defined as:

[image]

Note that if `a > b`, the major axis is horizontal and so you get a horizontally wide ellipse.  If `b > a`, the major axis is vertical and so you get a vertically wide ellipse.  This won't affect our code though.

Now, what we will do is we will have a `while` loop that keeps iterating and populating your image **until** a certain proportion of your image is full.  We then stop after we fill up this many pixels.  For now, I'll choose 40% of the total image.

Therefore, do something like this, assuming that you know the maximum `a` and `b` to be used in the image.  I would make them both equal so that you have an equal change generating horizontally and vertically wide ellipses:

```
%// Declare output image
out = zeros(200,200);

%// Declare a and b
a = 20;
b = 20;

%// Declare reference coordinates
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:size(out,2), 1:size(out,1));

%// Proportion
prop = 0.4;

%// Set seed for reproducibility
rng(123123);

while true
    %// Generate random a, b and centre
    x_axis = a*rand;
    y_axis = b*rand;
    centre = [size(out,2)*rand size(out,1)*rand];

    %// Define coordinates with respect to this centre
    Xmove = X - centre(1);
    Ymove = Y - centre(2);

    %// Check ellipse equation and filter out those locations
    %// that satisfy result
    ind = (((Xmove.^2) / x_axis^2) + ((Ymove.^2) / y_axis^2)) <= 1;

    %// Set these locations in the output image to a random intensity
    intensity = floor(223*rand) + 32;        
    out(ind) = intensity;

    %// Check proportion
    if sum((out(:) > 0) / numel(out)) >= prop
        break;
    end
end

%// Cast and show the output
out = uint8(out);
imshow(out);
```

---

This code probably requires some explanation.  We first declare an output image of a given size, and we also declare the minimum and maximum values of `a` and `b`.  We also define a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of points so that we can use this to generate our spatial coordinates for each ellipse we generate.

We define a proportion that we want the image to be filled before we quit, so I chose 40% here and I set the random seed to be 123123 through [`rng`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

Now, we will keep looping until the proportion of pixels that are being filled in the image either is equal to or exceeds this proportion.  At each iteration of the loop, we generate our `a`, `b` and our centres ensuring that they respect the boundaries of the image.  We then offset our reference grid of coordinates so that the random centre is now the origin, and we check to see which points in this new grid of coordinates satisfies the ellipse equation.  Whichever points satisfy the equation, we set these points in the image to a random intensity between `[32,255]`.  Bear in mind that I chose the **less than** inequality so that we can fill the ellipse.  I also made sure to choose a minimum intensity of 32 on purpose so that we can count how many pixels in the filled up image have been filled in.  To determine how much the image has been filled up, we count how many non-zero pixels there are, and see how much this proportion is and compare with our desired proportion.  If it's equal to or greater, we stop.  If not, we keep generating ellipses until this proportion is met.

With all of that, this is what I get with a run-through of the above code.

[image]

Comment: Nice way to fill the ellipses ... thought almost the same to compute them but thought using `annotation('ellispse', [x y w h])` for rendering.

Comment: Could also add for random orientation ;)

Comment: @CitizenInsane - Oh yes that could work! lol. I didn't do that because I figured the OP wanted an image to work with judging by their original code.  That's still a good way to do it.  As for the orientation.... ah... that would be cool, but I think I'll leave it :) lol. I think I've done enough!

Comment: Sure ... Good job! :)

Comment: @rayryeng: Thanks for your code, I am wondering that how I can set the probability distribution for the axis? For example, I want to use lognormal distribution.

Comment: @Sam - You can use whichever random generation method you want.  Check here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/random-number-generation.html.  I used `rand`, which is a uniform distribution.

Comment: You used "rand" to allocate the center, am I right? Indeed, I want to use a lognormal distribution of the "a" and "b" (axis)

Comment: Yes I did. This draws from a uniform distribution.  If you want lognormal, try using `lognrnd`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/lognrnd.html

Comment: @Divakar - Yup lol.  knedlsepp seems to have picked it up too.  I think I will suggest this on Meta.

Comment: @rayryeng We are having another "mentalist" talk [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681577/matlab-removing-zeros-and-then-vertically-collapse-the-matrix/28681688?noredirect=1#comment45662751_28681688). Seems like it could be a hot meta post haha ;)