# Matlab - Multidimensional Arrays Confusion

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have this 4 integer value output

example:

```
 out = [ 8     7     6     5 ]
```

I would to save these 4 values in one place (in row i column j)

Such that when I try to access

`array(i,j)` I get the 4 values `8 7 6 5`

I'm failing miserably. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the number of values is **the same** for all `i`, and `j`, use a [**3D array**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) of size `M`x`N`x`4`:

   ```
   array(1,1,:) = [8 7 6 5];
   array(1,2,:) = [11 12 13 14];
   ```

   You could imagine the four numbers are stacked on top of each other along a "depth" dimension in row `i` and column `j`.

   `array(i,j,:)` gives the 1x1x4 array containing the four numbers corresponding to `i`, `j`. When accesing each group of four numbers, you may want to use `squeeze` to remove the singleton dimensions, i.e. to obtain the result as a column vector:

   ```
   >> squeeze(array(1,1,:))
   ans =
    8
    7
    6
    5
   ```
2. If the number of values may be **different** for each `i` and `j`, use a 2D [**cell array**](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html):

   ```
   array{1,1} = [8 7 6 5];
   array{1,2} = [11 12];
   ```

   So `array{i,j}` gives the vector:

   ```
   >> array{1,1}
   ans =
        8     7     6     5
   ```

Comment: I wasn't sure of what OP wanted, but guess you have honed up your *mentalist* skills pretty well!

Comment: @Divakar Haha. Let's just wait for rayryeng to find a way to automatically detect mentalist-like questions and propose that badge on Meta!

Comment: @LuisMendo *automatically detect*? Like a bot? That would be epic! It must be called `mentobot`.

Comment: @LuisMendo - lol.  I have not written a post on Meta yet because I'm trying to find a good way to automatically detect mentalist-like questions because so far it seems the best way to do that is to do it manually.

Comment: @Divakar Nice one! So we already have a name. Rayryeng and I thought it had to be automatic so that the badge can be assigned by the system. I think that's how other badges work. It would be something like: _"mentalist": (badge description): Answering more than xxx questions with yyy criterion_

Comment: @LuisMendo Wow! You guys are serious! Well that automatic detection could be tricky though, maybe it could be based on the negative votes, number of close votes,etc. so that could come close to `reversal` badge.

Comment: @Divakar Exactly! That's [what I tought too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665153/how-do-i-find-the-maximum-of-each-dimension-in-a-cell-array-of-matrices#comment45626339_28665186). It's tricky